# Purpose of "subsd 0x0(%rip),%xmm0"

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm trying to understand/debug a library I don't have source code for. In doing so, I came across the following function (and a bunch of other, more complicated, ones like it, e.g. [0]):

```
0000000000000000 <old_bern_poly_power02(double, double)>:
       0:       66 0f 28 d0             movapd %xmm0,%xmm2
       4:       66 0f 28 c1             movapd %xmm1,%xmm0
       8:       f2 0f 59 d1             mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm2
       c:       f2 0f 5c 05 00 00 00    subsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 14 <old_bern_poly_power02(double, double)+0x14>
      13:       00
      14:       f2 0f 59 c2             mulsd  %xmm2,%xmm0
      18:       c3                      retq
      19:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

It's pretty obvious what the function does apart from the subsd instruction. However, I am confused about what the subsd instruction is doing. What does the value at the pointed to instruction, 0x0(%rip), have to do with this calculation?

So, this is my question: *What is the purpose of the "subsd" instruction above?* I assume the function was compiled with GCC. Why would GCC (or an assembly language programmer) include an instruction like this? [1]

---

[0] Here's another, similar example:

```
0000000000000020 <old_bern_poly_power03(double, double)>:
      20:       66 0f 28 d0             movapd %xmm0,%xmm2
      24:       66 0f 28 d8             movapd %xmm0,%xmm3
      28:       66 0f 28 c1             movapd %xmm1,%xmm0
      2c:       f2 0f 59 15 00 00 00    mulsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm2        # 34 <old_bern_poly_power03(double, double)+0x14>
      33:       00
      34:       f2 0f 5c 05 00 00 00    subsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 3c <old_bern_poly_power03(double, double)+0x1c>
      3b:       00
      3c:       f2 0f 59 d9             mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm3
      40:       f2 0f 59 c3             mulsd  %xmm3,%xmm0
      44:       f2 0f 58 c2             addsd  %xmm2,%xmm0
      48:       f2 0f 59 c3             mulsd  %xmm3,%xmm0
      4c:       c3                      retq
      4d:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
```

---

[1] Note: Based on stepping through the function in gdb, the subsd instruction seems to have no practical effect when %xmm0 is away from 0.0, because 0x0(%rip) is tiny (I am not sure this is correct):

```
(gdb) x $rip
0x4004e2 <old_bern_poly_power02+12>:    0x00000000055c0ff2
(gdb) p (double)(void *)(0x00000000055c0ff2)
$22 = 4.4426122995515177e-316
```

To investigate the effect of the subsd instruction further, I made a version of the old_bern_poly_power02 function that does not include the subsd instruction, but is otherwise identical to the listing above. The following table compares the return values of each version of the function given a variety of inputs.

Indeed, the return values are identical except when the xmm1 argument is 0, in which case the result is -0 (0x8000000000000000) in the original and 0 (0x0) in the version without the subsd instruction.

```
    xmm0     xmm1 ret_val_with_subsd           (as hex) ret_val_without_subsd           (as hex)
0.000000 0.000000      -0.0000000000 (8000000000000000)          0.0000000000 (               0)
0.000000 1.000000       0.0000000000 (               0)          0.0000000000 (               0)
0.000000 2.000000       0.0000000000 (               0)          0.0000000000 (               0)
0.000000 3.000000       0.0000000000 (               0)          0.0000000000 (               0)
1.000000 0.000000      -0.0000000000 (8000000000000000)          0.0000000000 (               0)
1.000000 1.000000       1.0000000000 (3ff0000000000000)          1.0000000000 (3ff0000000000000)
1.000000 2.000000       4.0000000000 (4010000000000000)          4.0000000000 (4010000000000000)
1.000000 3.000000       9.0000000000 (4022000000000000)          9.0000000000 (4022000000000000)
2.000000 0.000000      -0.0000000000 (8000000000000000)          0.0000000000 (               0)
2.000000 1.000000       2.0000000000 (4000000000000000)          2.0000000000 (4000000000000000)
2.000000 2.000000       8.0000000000 (4020000000000000)          8.0000000000 (4020000000000000)
2.000000 3.000000      18.0000000000 (4032000000000000)         18.0000000000 (4032000000000000)
3.000000 0.000000      -0.0000000000 (8000000000000000)          0.0000000000 (               0)
3.000000 1.000000       3.0000000000 (4008000000000000)          3.0000000000 (4008000000000000)
3.000000 2.000000      12.0000000000 (4028000000000000)         12.0000000000 (4028000000000000)
3.000000 3.000000      27.0000000000 (403b000000000000)         27.0000000000 (403b000000000000)
```

---

Edit 1: Per Harold and Ross's comments, I linked the library into a simple executable (the one that generated the above table) and disassembled the function in GDB, as follows:

```
$ gdb ./tmp
[snp]
(gdb) b old_bern_poly_power02 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400516
(gdb) r
Starting program: [...]/tmp 
    xmm0     xmm1 ret_val_with_subsd           (as hex) ret_val_without_subsd           (as hex)

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400516 in old_bern_poly_power02 ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function old_bern_poly_power02:
=> 0x0000000000400516 <+0>:     movapd %xmm0,%xmm2
   0x000000000040051a <+4>:     movapd %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x000000000040051e <+8>:     mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm2
   0x0000000000400522 <+12>:    subsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x40052a <old_bern_poly_power02+20>
   0x000000000040052a <+20>:    mulsd  %xmm2,%xmm0
   0x000000000040052e <+24>:    retq   
   0x000000000040052f <+25>:    nopl   (%rax)
End of assembler dump.
```

It seems to still have the same reference to 0-offset-to-%rip here, though it's definitely possible that I am still doing something wrong?

---

Edit 2: In the above listing, I was disassembling a version I'd copied and pasted from a disassembly of the unlinked static library, then assembled and linked into my test program above. When I disassemble the function from the original static library, as linked into my real program, the offsets are indeed filled in:

```
(gdb) disassemble old_bern_poly_power02
Dump of assembler code for function _Z21old_bern_poly_power02dd:
   0x00007f65cf642a50 <+0>:     movapd %xmm0,%xmm2
   0x00007f65cf642a54 <+4>:     movapd %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x00007f65cf642a58 <+8>:     mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm2
   0x00007f65cf642a5c <+12>:    subsd  0x38cc(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x7f65cf646330
   0x00007f65cf642a64 <+20>:    mulsd  %xmm2,%xmm0
   0x00007f65cf642a68 <+24>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

So I guess that the subsd instruction is just referencing a constant in a table here.

Comment: Seeing addresses (or offsets) that are zero is typical of code that hasn't been linked, did you disassemble a static library without linking it?

Comment: Try disassembling it with GDB when you're running the code. At that point the program should be fully linked and the correct offset should be in place.

Comment: Harold and Ross, thanks, I did not know that. You're right - I disassembled a static library without linking it. I edited the question with a listing of a disassembly of it in GDB, but the 0 offset still seems to be there?

Comment: Looks like the something when wrong when linking or the library is broken some how.

Comment: Oh I see - in the above, I'd copied/pasted the disassembled (from the static library) function into a source file and assembled it from scratch. So, that explains why disassembling in GDB didn't help. When I disassemble in GDB the original version of the function in the static library, but linked into my program, the offsets are filled in. Thanks again for your help here.

Comment: You can also use `objdump -drR` to see relocation entries.